# My swf file in my web server can not load json file from another server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash

I have a swf file in the root of my server named MyREOPS.swf  . And there is "index.html" in the root which embeds this swf. MyREOPS.swf in the server loads the link a json file from an xml, which is also in the same server.  Then my swf file, loads the json file, using this link it retrieved from the xml. So, here is my questions and problems :

Problems :

When I run swf in my local pc, it loads this json file from external domain url without problem, provided that the folder which contains the swf has permission ( I gave permission through http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html ).  However, when I run the MyREOPS.swf in the webserver through browser, i get this error :

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://www.3facts-engineering.com/MyREOPS.swf cannot load data from http://api.video.mail.ru/videos/mail/kulukamuluka/1/19.json.
```

Weird thing is the swf file was able to read the xml in the web server. I can understand this ,because it was actually able to see this link : "http://api.video.mail.ru/videos/mail/kulukamuluka/1/19.json". This was ONLY in that xml.

Aren't swf files, downloaded through browser to user's pc, then executed ? How is it possible for that swf to read the xml in the server. I mean that is what I would like it to do. But it feels like it is impossible for that swf to reach that xml while it run in my pc, because the url of xml in swf is given as relative such as "config.xml" .

I hope I was able to express myself throughly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature implemented by the Flash runtime.

[Cross-domain policy for Flash movies](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html)

> For security reasons, a Macromedia Flash movie playing in a web
>   browser is not allowed to access data that resides outside the exact
>   web domain from which the SWF originated.

When you run locally, your SWF is executing in Flash Projector; therefore, operates differently than when embedded from your site.

On the site you wish to connect, create a crossdomain.xml file, as in:

```
http://example.com/crossdomain.xml
```

Within that crossdomain.xml, add parameters, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="80,443"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is Mr Sturges, that I am trying to reach "http://api.video.mail.ru/videos/mail/kulukamuluka/1/19.json" internally, in the swf AS3 codes. I kinda have to do it this way for some reasons. And according to the way crossdomain.xml works, i think the xml must be in the domain "mail.ru" which is where the json file is. Am i right ? And I dont have access to accomplish that.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Perhaps you could contact the site asking them to change their policy, as they currently prevent this type of access.  Your only other option is to use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to bridge a JavaScript call from the browser to Flash player.